# Add CSS ClassName dynamically in React loop Based on Condition

Tags: reactjs

I have react component the loop through data. I need to check add ClassName dynamically based on one of the field '{stateItem.transactionCoverStatus}' value.

Let's say if `transactionCoverStatus == x` then `color-blue` else `if == y` then `color-red`.. and so on.

There are about 5 possible values so also wonder if I can calculate in separate method which takes parameter and return class name!

```
  <tbody>
      {
         eziTransactionCollection.map((stateItem, stateIndex) =>(

           <tr key={stateIndex}>
              <td className="td-align-centre">{stateItem.eziTransactionId}</td>
              <td>{stateItem.transactionCoverStatus}</td>
              <td>{stateItem.loginDateTime}</td>
              <td>{stateItem.logoutDateTime}</td>
            </tr>
         ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object to map the class variants and pass your status to retrieve the value:

```
const COVER_COLORS = {
  active: 'blue',
  disabled: 'gray',
  warning: 'yellow',
}

const coverClass = (coverStatus) => {
  const variant = COVER_COLORS[coverStatus]
  return variant ? `color-${variant}` : '' // or return a default class
}

...

           <tr key={stateIndex}>
              <td className="td-align-centre">{stateItem.eziTransactionId}</td>
              <td className={coverClass(stateItem.transactionCoverStatus)}>{stateItem.transactionCoverStatus}</td>
              <td>{stateItem.loginDateTime}</td>
              <td>{stateItem.logoutDateTime}</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to give a condition on classname in react

`:` means **else**.

`?` means **then**.

```
 <td className={stateItem.transactionCoverStatus==='x' ? 'blue' : 'red'}>{stateItem.transactionCoverStatus}</td>
```

If you want to give multiple conditions. You should use `||` operator

```
<td className={stateItem.transactionCoverStatus==='x' || stateItem.transactionCoverStatus==='y'  ?  'red' : 'green'}>{stateItem.transactionCoverStatus}</td>
```